# How to create a new column from a subset of other existing columns?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset that contains monthly GDP from 2000-2016, indexed by State and City. The columns representing GDP are formatted by 'year-month', so for example, '2000-01' represents January 2000. I am trying to get the GDP by fiscal quarter, where each quarter is the mean of the corresponding month's GDP.

Here is a snippet of the dataframe (disregard the values as they are just for the example).

```
State    City        2000-01   2000-02   2000-03   2000-04   2000-05   2000-06 
Alabama  Adamsville  1000      1005      1020      1119      1125      1000
Alabama  Alabaster   1093      1312      1542      1624      1134      1953
Alabama  Axis        18324     98174     14047     27343     43234     12434
```

My expected output is as follows (again, the values are made up). As an example, 2000q1 is the mean of the columns 2000-01, 2000-02, and 2000-03.

```
State    City        2000q1   2000q2 
Alabama  Adamsville  1010     1006
Alabama  Alabaster   1100     1750
Alabama  Axis        15673    19849
```

I have tried several different ways, most notably:

Because the output dataframe will have 64 different quarters, it is inefficient to do the following for each quarter:

```
df['2000q1']=df[['2000-01', '2000-02', '2000-03']].mean(axis=1)
```

In another attempt I changed all the column names to represent the quarter they should be apart of, resulting in three identical column names (but not underlying data) for each quarter, as seen below. Because the column names were identical, I then struggled in finding the mean for each trio of identical column names.

```
State    City        2000q1    2000q1    2000q1    2000q2    2000q2    2000q2 
Alabama  Adamsville  1000      1005      1020      1119      1125      1000
Alabama  Alabaster   1093      1312      1542      1624      1134      1953
Alabama  Axis        18324     98174     14047     27343     43234     12434
```

Answer (score 1):

I think i once worked on a similar problem on Coursera.com. You can try this (assuming that the name of your data frame is 'df'):

```
df = (df.groupby(pd.PeriodIndex(df.columns, freq='Q'), axis=1).mean())
```

You will get column names like '2000Q1'. If you want to get the names as '2000q1', you can try this:

```
df = (df.groupby(pd.PeriodIndex(df.columns, freq='Q'), axis=1).mean().rename(columns=lambda c: str(c).lower()))
```

Answer (score 0):

assume your dataframe as `df`

```
data = df.iloc[:,2:]
predf = df.iloc[:,:2]
colnums = [i for i in range(0,len(data.columns),3)]
newdf = pd.DataFrame()
for idx,val in enumerate(colnums):
    name = data.columns[idx].split("-")[0]
    colname = f"{name}-q{idx+1}"
    newdf[colname] = data.iloc[:,val:(val+2)].mean(axis=1)

output = pd.concat([predf,newdf],axis=1)
```